# How to highlight or put a box around one item in enumerate?

Tags: enumerate

```
\item The sum $3-\dfrac{3}{10}+\dfrac{3}{100}-\dfrac{3}{1000} 
      + \cdots + \dfrac{(-1)^k3}{10^k} + \cdots$ is closest to:
\begin{enumerate}
\item[(a)] $\dfrac{2}{e}$
\item[(b)] $2$
\item[(c)] $e$
\item[(d)] $e^2$
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: There is much too little information here to allow anyone to guess at what you want.  Even a scanned image of a hand-drawn example would be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to tex.se! At the moment it's hard to understand what your question is. Could you please add a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/172164) and explain what you're looking for? You could for example add an illustration of your desired end result. You can also look for similar questions in the past, for example [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261304/172164) or [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17105/172164) or [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25904/172164).

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE. Please, inform a little bit more clear what you want, preferably with a MWE.

Answer (score 6):

Judging by the code snippet you posted, your document employs the `amsmath` package. This package provides a macro called `\framebox`, which (a) should be used in math mode and (b) places a rectangular frame around its argument. I'm assuming that this is what you want to achieve when you wrote that you wish to "put a box around one item" in an `enumerate` environment.

Two other methods for highlighting objects with color are provided by the `xcolor` package: `\colorbox{<background color>}{<object>}` and `\fcolorbox{<frame color>}{<background color>}{<object>}`. These macros may be used in either text or math mode.

There are still other methods for highlighting or placing box frames around objects. The earlier comment by @TivV points to several postings (and associated answers) that present such methods.

The following code (a) makes your code more LaTeX-idiomatic (e.g., by using `\dots` and `\dotsb` in lieu of `\cdots`) and (b) illustrates the use of `\framebox`, `\colorbox`, and `\fcolorbox`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\framebox" macro
\usepackage{xcolor}  % for "\colorbox" and "\fcolorbox" macros
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item The sum $\displaystyle 3-\frac{3}{10}+\frac{3}{100}
      - \frac{3}{1000} + \dots + \frac{(-1)^k 3}{10^k} 
      + \dotsb$ is closest to:
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item $\dfrac{2}{e}$
\item $\framebox{e}$
\item \colorbox{yellow}{$e^2$}
\item $\fcolorbox{orange}{green}{2}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot!

Comment: Too bad `colorbox` does not wrap text and puts everything on one line instead.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Qais Karaki and Welcome to TeX-SE.

I'm guessing your want to highlight the content after the `\item`than the `item` itself.

If you want to highlight the number or mark in `\item`, please check TivV comment.

There some options to put a box around the content after `\item`, which are indeed just a variation to putting a box around any text.

A MWE follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item
            \begin{tcolorbox}[width=145mm, halign=center, colframe=black, colback=white, boxsep=0mm, arc=3mm]
                \parbox{135mm}{\lipsum[1]}
            \end{tcolorbox}
    \item
        \begin{tcolorbox}[width=145mm, halign=center, colframe=black, colback=yellow!80!black, boxsep=0mm, arc=3mm]
            \parbox{135mm}{\lipsum[2]}
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \item 
    \framebox[135mm][c]{%
        Not to long text
    }
    \item 
    \framebox{\parbox[c]{135mm}{\lipsum[3]}}
    \item 
        \begin{tcolorbox}[width=145mm, halign=center, colframe=blue, colback=red!80!white, boxsep=0mm, arc=0mm]
            \parbox{135mm}{ %
                \begin{equation}
                    \dfrac{y}{x}
                \end{equation}
            }
        \end{tcolorbox}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]